# ApplicationClass.Documents.Open throwing System.InvalidCastException

Tags: c#, .net, exception

I am working on a project built on .NET 4.5 that references a .dll built on .NET 3.5.

This error has come up before and my coworker was able to find a solution that involved either adding or removing a registry key, but he is unable to remember how he found the solution.

There is also a lot of hub-bub out on this site and on the internet about how to take care of this exception, and it might be nice to find a generic solution if it is possible.

Here is what I know: this error is thrown by the following line of code:

```
ApplicationClass AC = new ApplicationClass();
```

I have read elsewhere that the use of the ApplicationClass is now frowned upon, but there isn't much I can do about it at this point as the .dll that it's used in is in use across multiple applications that I'm not able to touch.

Anyway, the problem is that after this line executes, each of AC's fields are not initialized, rather, they throw a System.InvalidCastException.

However, this doesn't cause an issue by itself. It is only when the following line is execute that the actual exception that causes the problem is thrown:

```
AC.Documents.Open(filePath, true);
```

Below is the error that is thrown by the outer application running on .NET 4.5.

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
2016-07-14 09:40:22  Error  9  System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast COM object of type 'LabelManager2.ApplicationClass' to interface type 'LabelManager2.IApplication'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{3624B9C3-9E5D-11D3-A896-00C04F324E22}' failed due to the following error: No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)).
   at System.RuntimeType.InvokeDispMethod(String name, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Object target, Object[] args, Boolean[] byrefModifiers, Int32 culture, String[] namedParameters)
   at System.RuntimeType.InvokeMember(String name, BindingFlags bindingFlags, Binder binder, Object target, Object[] providedArgs, ParameterModifier[] modifiers, CultureInfo culture, String[] namedParams)
   at System.RuntimeType.ForwardCallToInvokeMember(String memberName, BindingFlags flags, Object target, Int32[] aWrapperTypes, MessageData& msgData)
   at LabelManager2.ApplicationClass.Quit()
```

Does anyone know how to solve this issue? I have tried methods from other threads on StackOverflow to no avail and would very much appreciate any help!

Comment: It looks like you are using COM.  Did you register the COM dll?

Answer (score -1):

This ended up being solvable by removing the version I was working on (v1.2), installing and uninstalling the previous version (v1.1), then reinstalling v1.2.

I tried to manually register the dlls that I was using using regasm.exe but it would not register for some reason unknown to me.

Short form: Install previous version to have it register necessary dlls.